# ¿Cómo solucionar AttributeError:'bool' object has no attribute 'wait_for_press'?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Estoy realizando un código como se ve, el ejecuta la primera vez el *while* todo bien, pero al realizar por segunda vez el *while* me sale el error en el botón:

> AttributeError:'bool' object has no attribute 'wait_for_press'

Este es mi código:

```
import requests
import json
import webbrowser
import time
import os  
import gpiozero

#global boton 
#boton = gpiozero.Button(26)


def reporte():
    print('funciona')    

def cita():
    print('funciona')

def sos():
    print('sos')

def boton_press():
    #boton = gpiozero.Button(26)
    bandera = True
    bandera_2 = True
    
    while bandera:
        try:
            boton = True

            if (boton and bandera_2 == True ):
                
                print ("seccion iniciada")
                
            
            elif(boton != bandera_2):
                
                print('seccion terminada')
                print(boton) #imprime estado del boton 
                break

        except:
            print("error inesperado")
            break
        bandera = True

boton = gpiozero.Button(26)
while True :
    try:
        #
        
        print('inicia')
        time.sleep(1)
        cita_activa = reporte()
        boton = boton.wait_for_press(1)
        print(boton)
        
    
        if cita_activa == True:
            cita()

        if boton == True:
            boton_press()
        

    
    except:
        print('error con el dispositivo')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestra la segunda ejecución, la ejecución la hice con la función *debug* del thommy de *raspberryPi*, la primera vez se ejecuta sin ningún problema y al volver a realizarla sale el error anteriormente mencionado.

Comment: decídete!, estas asignando el valor de `True` (o un valor booleano) a la variable `boton` pero luego estas usando un método `wait_for_press(1)` lo cual no es correcto, tu código internamente queda `True.wait_for_press(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Primero dices que `boton` es un objeto `Button

```
boton = gpiozero.Button(26)
```

y pocas líneas más adelante, dices:

```
boton = boton.wait_for_press(1)
```

con lo cual has reemplazado un objeto `Button` con lo que retorna la función `wait_for_press`, que parece ser un booleano, según el mensaje de error.

Si necesitas el resultado de la función para alguna otra cosa, dale un nombre distinto:

```
boton_wait = boton.wait_for_press(1)
```

por ejemplo ...

Comment: listo muchas gracias por la aclaración, lo cambiare y veré que pasa